# Why this code showing different output as when working on online compilers and on turbo ide?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main ()
{
    int i;
    printf ("Hello");
    char s[]= 
       {'\b','\t','\r','\n'};
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
       printf("%c",s[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `Hello` on online compilers but `Hell` on turbo c++

Comment: `\b` is Backspace

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, the characters of `Hello\b\t\r\n` will be sent to the console. The last four are escape codes which translate to backspace, tab, carriage return, newline. The console you're using with turboc++ is behaving like you might expect -- backspace is deleting the `o`. The online compilers are presumably treating it differently.

Comment: I wonder about that online compilers presumably *"erase"* the backspace behavior. Should definitely not be. I´m excited about if there is a actual reason for this.

Comment: As side note: Maybe it would be worth to mention to not use the out-dating, obsolete and not C standard conforming Turbo C++.